# Replace rule inside mathematical operations

Tags: functions

This is probably very trivial question. I want to replace `D[G[0,2,1,x],x]` where $D(0,2,1,x)$ is anything but the number of arguments may change keeping $x$ fixed, with `D[W[0,2,1,x],x`. But when I write

```
D[G[2, 1, x], x] /. D[G[pp__, x], x] :> D[W[pp, x], x]
```

this does not work.

I will elaborate the actual context. This can be interesting. `PolyLogTools` is a amazing package which can handle the recursive integrals very easily. First it transforms some known functions in term of GPL function. For example $log(x)=G(0,x)$. Then it can do differentiation by `DG[G[0,x],x]` equal to $1/x$, or integrations by `GIntegrate`.

In some of my work, I am working with GPL functions using `polyLogTools`. There a package is giving output `D[G[0,1,x],x]`. Since `D` does not understand GPLs, it gives

```
Out[10] := G^(0,0,1)[0,1,x]
```

So, manually I want to convert these outputs in term of GPLs. However when I apply

```
D[G[0, 1, x], x] /. {D[G[aa__, x], x] :> DG[G[aa, x], x]}
```

this does not work and still gives

```
Out[12] := G^(0,0,1)[0,1,x]
```

The Holding mentioned by @Acus is also not working.

```
In[16] := Hold[(G^(0,0,1))[1,1,x]]/. HoldPattern[D[G[pp__,x],x]]:>DG[G[pp,x],x]//ReleaseHold
Out[16] := (G^(0,0,1))[1,1,x]
```

Is there any other method available?

Comment: (Hold[D[G[2, 1, x], x]] /. {HoldPattern[D[G[pp__, x], x]] :> 
     D[W[pp, x], x]}) // ReleaseHold     The primary reason is that LHS is evaluated. Also I suggest that your hold the replacement pattern, since it is also inclined to evaluate.

Comment: `D[G[2, 1, x], x] /. G -> W`?

Answer (score 2):

To better understand what is happening, write ReplaceAll in full form like:

```
ReplaceAll[D[G[2, 1, x], x], D[G[pp__, x], x] :> D[W[pp, x], x]]
```

Now, ReplaceAll will evaluates all its arguments because it does not have the attribute HoldAll. Therefore, D[G[pp__, x], x] :> D[W[pp, x], x] will evaluate. FullForm of this is:

```
RuleDelayed[D[G[pp__, x], x], D[W[pp, x], x]]
```

This will also evaluate its arguments. And the problem arises from D[G[pp__, x], x]. The differential operator "D" does no pattern matching and considers  pp___ as one argument and it will evaluate G as a function of only 2 arguments.

The second problem comes from the full form of D[G[2, 1, x], x]. This is: Derivative[0,0,1][G][2,1,x], different from the input.

Therefore, what need be done is: prevent changing the original function to full form and evaluation of D[G[pp__, x], x]. This can be done by "Hold" and "HoldPattern":

```
Hold[D[G[2, 1, x], x]] /. HoldPattern[ D[G[pp__, x], x]] :> D[W[pp, x], x] // ReleaseHold
```

[image]